# Jenkins pipeline groovy store matched regex string in variable

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a `string` in a `jenkinsfile` and I am trying to create a new variable based on a regex match of that string. For example:

```
def stringA = "Hello World Today"

def stringB = stringA =~ /Hello/

echo stringB
```

I expect to see `Hello` echo in the console but I only get what seems to be a reference to a regex object.

I cannot seem to achieve what I am trying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this situation, `stringB` would indeed be assigned a value of a regular expression object. You need to use the syntax to capture a substring within the regular expression. This is `()` in Groovy and most other interpreted languages as well:

```
def stringB = stringA =~ /(Hello)/
```

The value of `stringB` at this point would be a nested array where each element is an array containing values for the matching substring of each `()` within the regular expression. In this situation, there is only one `()`, so we access the zeroth element and then the nested element containing the substring for the match, which is the element at one:

```
print stringB[0][1]
```

This will return `Hello`.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness adding search with a variable and full block that can used in function.

```
def stringToMatch = '''<PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.18.4" />'''
def toSearch = "Moq"
def result = stringToMatch =~ /${toSearch}\" Version=\"(.+)\"

if (result) { 
    println "Found Moq verson ${result[0][1]}"
} 
else{
    println "Nothing found"
}
```